# Etymology of 'troia' with respect to the City of Troy?

Tags: etymology, swearwords

Is there any connection between the Italian name for the city of Troy, "Troia", and the pejorative term 'troia'? Do native speakers figuratively reference the city in this expression, or is it simply coincidental?

(I'm imagining some description of Troy as a harlot in Ovid, or similar...)

I'm working with an 18th-century opera, and a sentence in the libretto mentioning Troy is missing from the musical score: so I don't know whether it's simply a practical cut or as a result of any sensibility.

Comment: The "pejorative term" (insult, really) is a female pig.

Comment: Forgot to add: there is no connection to the name of the city. The word can be written alternatively as "troja", while the name of the city, for example in English, is written with Y (Troy).

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica While I agree that there is no connection to the name of the city, I wouldn't take the English spelling as relevant (after all the name comes to Italian from Greek via Latin, and *i* and *j* were considered the same latter until fairly recently). In fact there are [nineteenth century texts](https://books.google.de/books?id=V8S8GCVFoEYC&pg=PA42&dq=%22troja%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA5vfyxejoAhUMC-wKHexHDWsQ6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q=%22troja%22&f=false) writing the city as *Troja*.

Comment: Italian "troia" is probably a cognate of French "truie" and Catalan "truja", which, as Italian "troia",  also mean "female of a pig".

Comment: My mother was born in the Italian city Troia in Apulia. When I visited Italy, the locals found it amusing when I said my mother was Troiana which they took to mean prostitute. My mother's family goes back generations in the town. Recent DNA test shows that our generation (my mother's children) have around 40% Greek heritage confirming to us at least, the strong connection to Greece & most likely to the Troy of antiquity. I studied opera and always felt there was a strong link to the story if Dido & Aeneas to our maternal home town. I believe that English composers of Henry Purcell's time looke

Comment: @Ermina There's also a legend about Brutus from Troy who 'founded' Britain, in parallel to the Aeneas legend. But I digress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not completely clear if Italian word "troia" is etymologically related to the name of the city of Troy.

[Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/troia), gives this origin

> lat. mediev. *troia*, forse voce espressiva che imita il grugnito del maiale

that is, it comes from Medieval Latin *troia*, that could be simply an expressive term that imitates the grunt of the pig.

Nevertheless, [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000401.jpg) provides this explanation about the etymology of Italian "troia":

> Dal  lat.  mediev. *troia* (nel  sec.  VIlI),  solitamente  fatto  de­rivare  dal  nome  di  un  piatto  tipico  della  gastronomia  romana, il *porcus troiānus*, un  maiale  arrostito  e  farcito  di  altri  animali, successivamente  chiamato 
>   *porcus  de  Troia* e  infine,  semplicemente, 
>   *troia*.  Altri  invece  ritiene  che  tale  preparazione  gastro­nomica,  menzionata  solo  in  Macrobio  (V  sec.),  non  sia  in  realtà mai  esistita  e  non  rappresenti  che  un'immaginazione  scherzo­sa;  il  termine *troia* sarebbe  quindi  una  semplice  formazione  popol. di origine espressiva.

That is, it comes from Medieval Latin *troia* (in the VIII century). It's believed that it could derive from the name of a typical dish of Roman gastronomy, called *porcus troiānus*, a roasted pig stuffed with other animals, later called *porcus de Troia* and finally, simply, *troia*. If it were that way, Italian *troia* would be etymologically related to the name of the city of Troy because Latin  *troiānus* comes from *Troia* (Greek *Tροία*). But this dictionary explains that others believe that this gastronomic preparation, mentioned only by Macrobius (V century), actually never existed and it's only fruit of a playful imagination;  the term *troia* would therefore be simply a formation of popular expressive origin (and it wouldn't be related to the name of the city of Troy).

[*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/truie) explains the etymology of French "truie" in a very similar way:

> Du b. lat. *troja* (VIII<sup>e</sup>  s. *Gl. de Cassel*, éd. P. Marchot, 80: *troia: suu*), d'orig. obsc. Il était tentant de rapprocher le mot de *porcus Trojanus* relevé une seule fois chez MARTIAL, *Saturn.*, III, 13, 13, formé d'apr. *equus trojanus*, pour désigner un porc farci, bourré de petit gibier (*porcum Trojanum mensis inferant, quem illi ideo sic vocabant quasi aliis inclusis animalibus gravidum ut ille Trojanus equus gravidus armatis fuit*); de *porcus Trojanus*, aurait été tiré [*porcus de*] *Troja*; cependant, il s'agit plus vraisemblablement d'un mot de création plaisante que de l'appellation habituelle d'un mets, ERN.-MEILLET; FEW t. 13, 2, p. 314 b. L'examen de l'aire géogr. de *truie* (dom. gallo-rom.; Italie du Nord; de la Catalogne et Sicile), ainsi que la forme *troga*, relevée par DU CANGE, *s.v. troga*, suggèrent à G. BREUER, ds *Z. fr. Spr. Lit.* t. 87, 1977, p. 170, un étymon gaul. **trogja*, formé du rad. **trŏgh* « tirer » (dont sont issus, notamment en a. et m. irl. des termes signifiant « fertile, productif ») et du suff. gaul. *-jā*.

I will try to translate it:

> From Medieval Latin *troja* (VIII century *Gl. de Cassel*, éd. P. Marchot, 80: *troia: suu*), of obscure origin.  It was tempting to relate it to the expression *porcus Trojanus* found only once in MARTIAL<sup>1</sup>, *Saturn.*, III, 13, 13, formed from *equus trojanus*, to designate a pig stuffed with other small animals, (*porcum Trojanum mensis inferant, quem illi ideo sic vocabant quasi aliis inclusis animalibus gravidum ut ille Trojanus equus gravidus armatis fuit*);  from *porcus Trojanus*, it would have been drawn [*porcus of*] *Troja*;  however, it is more likely a term of amusing creation than the usual name for a dish, ERN.-MEILLET;  FEW t.  13, 2, p.  314 b. The examination of the geographic area of *truie* (Gaul-Roman domain; Northern Italy; Catalonia and Sicily), as well as of the form *troga*, noted by DU CANGE, *s.v.  troga*, suggest to G. BREUER, ds *Z.  Fr.  Spr.  Lit.* t.  87, 1977, p. 170, a Gaul etymology  **trogja*, formed from the root  **trŏgh* (which in French means "tirer" and from which come some Old and Middle Irish terms meaning "fertile, productive") and Gaul suffix  *-jā*.

---

<sup>1. 
I don't understand why *Trésor de la langue française* says Martial instead of Macrobius, since the reference to *porcus troiānus* and its relation to the Trojan horse appears in *Saturnalia* III, 13, 13 by Macrobius, from which comes the excerpt quoted in this source.</sup>

Comment: Breton has *tourc'h* (from which *trouch*) as *pig*. Also, in the Sardinian dialect which borrows many words from Latin, *troju* means "dirty, filthy, pig": https://books.google.it/books?id=G-RGAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA590&ots=QCYflNf2z7&dq=trojazzu&pg=PA590#v=onepage&q=trojazzu&f=false

Comment: [Occitan](https://locongres.org/oc/aplicacions/dicodoc-oc/dicodoc-recerca?option=com_dicodoc&view=search&Itemid=168&type=fr-oc&q=truie) has also "trueja", "trueia" and other variants which are also cognates of "troia".

Answer (score 4):

There is probably no connection, and in any case not a direct one (as in the city personified or the like).

*Troia* as the name of the city is just a transcription of one of its Greek names, Τροία.

*Troia* meaning “sow” (and hence as a derogatory term for “prostitute”) is Medieval Latin word, perhaps originally imitating the grunting of the pig ([source](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/troia)). Zingarelli dictionary suggests instead that the Latin word might come from a dish, *pŏrcus Troiānus*, consisting of a stuffed pig, alluding to the Trojan Horse (but this explanation is given as uncertain).

<sub>As regards that opera, it may well be that, even if there is no etymological connection, the word was felt as inappropriate. In a far different context, in the Italian release of 2016 Disney film *Moana*, the eponymous protagonist has been renamed “Vaiana”, apparently, since Moana was the name of a famous Italian porn star.</sub>